# How is this directory hidden?

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions, nfs

I'm on a CentOS 7 server attempting to list a subdirectory. When I first list the top level directory, it appears empty:

```
[me@server ~]$ ls -al /misc
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    0 Mar 13 12:49 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 root root 4096 Feb  1 09:54 ..
```

However, there exists a subdirectory that I have read/execute permissions on, and can list:

```
[me@server ~]$ ls -al /misc/subdir
total 192
drwxr-xr-x. 50 root     root     4096 Feb 25 09:52 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root     root        0 Mar 13 12:49 ..
...other files and folders...
```

And after I list it for the first time it appears in the top level directory:

```
[me@server ~]$ ls -al /misc
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    0 Mar 13 12:49 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 root root 4096 Feb  1 09:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 50 root root 4096 Feb 25 09:52 subdir
```

But if I wait a while (10 minutes?) it disappears again. It's not a symlink, not a dotfile, and may be an NFS mount (not in the fstab but a `stat` of the folder returns `Context: system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0`). What could be causing this directory to be hidden until I attempt to access it?

Comment: What filesystem are `/misc` and `/misc/subdir`? Does `ls /misc/subdir` ever fail? Can you share the output of `findmnt -T /misc` and `findmnt -T /misc/subdir`?

Comment: Turned out to be an automounter, though I didn't know about the findmnt command which would have pointed me that direction too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely have automounter on top of /misc directory. Have a look at your /etc/auto.master and /etc/auto.misc files to figure out what is (auto)mounted there.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I'd never heard of an automounter before.